# how to tokenize a file by keeping delimiters?

Tags: c

I want to tokenize my tslang file and print tokens.

For example:

```
if(n==5)
```

should be transformed to

```
if ( n = = )
```

I use `strtok()` and give delimiters in the separator string, but that doesn't do what I want because I need to print the delimiters, too. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
main() {
    char str[128];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("c1.txt", "r");
    char sprate[] = " ( ) < >  / # * . , ; : ! ? - \" [ ] { } = ";

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("error!can't find file");
    else {
        while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)) {
            char *t = strtok(str, sprate);

            printf("\n");
            while (t != NULL){
                printf("%s\n", t);
                t = strtok(NULL, sprate);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep delimiters, you can't use `strtok()` — or `strsep()` or relatives.  Consider `strcspn()` (`strspn()` and `strpbrk()`).

Comment: In conjunction with using different string-analysis functions, you may want to look into some of the more advanced capabilities of `printf()` field directives.  I'm thinking in particular of specifying a precision in your `%s` directive -- specifically, [a *variable* one](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p5).